# How many skill / attribute points will I ever get for my character?

Tags: ragnarok-online-2

I downloaded and installed Ragnarok Online 2 yesterday. After having invested a number of years of my life in the original Ragnarok Online, I'm not sure this was the wisest decision, but who can resist those adorable Porings?!

Regardless, as I was setting things ablaze with my fireballs, I leveled up and got some skill and attribute points. After looking at the skill list, it got me wondering...

**After achieving max level, how many skill and attribute points will I have?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a definitive answer for how many points you can spend on your stats at max-lvl, but according to [a post in the official RO2 forum](http://forums.warpportal.com/index.php?/topic/111083-stats-guidefaq/), the highest you can get a stat is 51.

It is explained, that unlike the original RO, your stats won't matter much, since they'll be largely overshadowed by your gear.

For example: At 50 strength, you'll have 100 ATK. Your gear will add 2-5k (thousand) ATK, depending on your class.

Also worth noting:
- There is no need to skill both STR and INT, except if you're a Monk or Swordsman class.
- WIS is considered to be useless, regardless of your class.
- With no DEX, archer classes now need to skill STR in order to gain ATK

Here are a few commonly-accepted stat builds that apply to all classes (according to the forum):

50/26/2
26/50/2
40/40/0
39/39/7
3x/3x/3x

with the first number referring to either STR or INT, the second number to AGI, and the last to VIT

**[EDIT] As for the skill points:**
You start with 3 already assigned skill points and will earn 1 skill point per lvl-up. With 50 being the current level cap; this means you'll be able to spend 49 skill points upon reaching the maximum level, totalling 52 skill points.

According to some class skill builds available online, it appears that you no longer need to spend all skill points prior to changing class at level 25. This means, that you can theoretically spend more than 25 skill points for second-class skills. <strike>Unfortunately, I cannot confirm this personally, since I haven't reached level 25 yet.</strike> Confirmed, thanks to @Deruijter.

Comment: Thanks for the stats info, but there is no mention of skill points. Any idea on them?

Comment: @Aeo I edited my answer to add info about skill points (sorry I forgot to mention those)

Comment: Skill point saving confirmed. You can choose not to spend all your skill points in your first class so you can spend them when changing into your second class at lvl 25 (or higher).

Comment: @Deruijter Thanks for confirming this. I edited my answer accordingly.